# How to add a parameter to an API call function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to react and am sort of winging it.

I have the following Code:

```
 const handleDelete = e => {
    const token = getCookie('token');
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .delete(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user/delete/${id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      .then(res => {
        loadProfile(res, () => {
          toast.danger('Profile successfully deleted');
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response);
      });
  };
```

and it should create an API Request to delete a User from the Database and the request works fine and even if I hardcode the Id into the code above (for test purposes).

My plan is to call the `handleDelete` function with a button like this:

```
<button
...
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleDelete()}
      >
        <i className='fas fa-trash-alt  w-6  -ml-2' />
        Delete {user.name}
      </button>
```

My problem is that I need to parse in the id of the User to the `handleDelete` function and I tried to do it like this  `onClick={() => handleDelete(user._id)`

the problem is that if I then do it like this:

```
const handleDelete(id) = e => {
const token = getCookie('token');
...
```

I get an error that there is an unexpected token at `handleDelete(id)`

How can I fix this and send the id to the delete function
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const handleDelete = (e, id) => {...}` and `onClick={e => handleDelete(e, user._id)}` is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
const handleDelete(id) = e => {
```

Try to use

```
const handleDelete = (e, id) => {
```

And then on the button when you will set onClick handler use it like this

```
onClick={e => handleDelete(e, user._id)}
```